# pandas dataframe .loc copyerror

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to perfom basic operation on a pandas dataframe and I get this error

```
my_script.py:22: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-
docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
df['col_new'] = df['col2'] - df['col1'] + 1
```

changed it to:

```
df['col_new'] = df.loc['end'] - df.loc['start'] + 1
```

For which I get this error:

```
KeyError: 'the label [end] is not in the [index]'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The syntax is `df.loc[index, column]` so you would need `df.loc[:, 'end']` but I don't think it would solve your problem. You probably created your `df`  as a slice of another DataFrame. Check out the code before the warning.

Comment: I used it as second step after reading the df `df.loc[:, 'intron_size'] = df.loc[:, 'end'] - df.loc[:, 'start'] + 1`  but i still get the same error, at this point what I want to know is does it make any undesired operation if not will not worry about the warning

Comment: Consider this operation: `df = another_df[another_df['col']==2]` Now df is a slice of `another_df`. But it won't raise a warning at this point. Whenever you want to change `df`, you'll see that SettingWithCopyWarning. You can ignore the warning as long as you are aware that changing `df`  will not affect `another_df`. The `loc`  part is the solution for chained indexing and I don't think that's the issue here.

Comment: Note also that this warning isn't always correct.  The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing) observe, *"The chained assignment warnings / exceptions are aiming to inform the user of a possibly invalid assignment. There may be false positives; situations where a chained assignment is inadvertently reported."*

Comment: thanks, I kinda ignored that warning, and now I get this error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis` looks like a long day ahead